# How can I initialize a palette with matplotlib's colormap?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got the following code

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
# cm.spring() is a color map
# E.g., print(cm.spring(4)) outputs (1.0, 0.01568627450980392, 0.9843137254901961, 1.0) which is a RGB color
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
# Create a black image
img = Image.new('P', (100, 100))
NUM_OF_COLORS = 5
# I want my palette to consist of the first N elements of the color map
img.putpalette(matplotlib.cm.spring()[:NUM_OF_COLORS])
```

I.e., I know that there're N colors in my image, but I don't want to specify them manually, so I want to put `N` colors (from `matplotlib.cm` or any other color map) to a palette to use them as [indexed colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color) afterwards to create an light `png` image.

How should I change
`img.putpalette(matplotlib.cm.spring()[:NUM_OF_COLORS])` to make it work?

Comment: cm.spring should have 256 colors. The first 5 colors are almost the same. Also the new image contains only a single color; how do the five colors relate to the single color of the image?

Comment: I'll draw some polygons using the colors from the palette, so it won't be a single color image later on.